# How can I get CI session's userdata outside the application folder?

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter, session

I am trying to access codeigniter session's userdata from outside of the application folder. But I am getting an empty result.

```
define('STDIN', TRUE);
$_SERVER['argv'] = array();

ob_start();
require('../index.php');
ob_end_clean();

$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->load->library('session');

echo $CI->session->userdata('id');
print_r($CI->session);
exit;
```

I am getting this-

```
CI_Session Object ( [userdata] => [_driver:protected] => files [_config:protected] => )
```

Comment: Please try this statement for access session value `$sess = unserialize($_COOKIE['ci_session']);`

Comment: That is not worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it whenever you like to use like following:

Whenever you want to use just start the session by session_start() function and access the variable as following:

```
print_r($_COOKIE['ci_session']);
```

By this way, you'll be able to use the session values of CI outside the application folder.

Hope this will help you..